# How to fill black region by white inside a write circular shaped object using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to detect black region inside a write circular or semi circular shaped object and then fill it with white color. Here, I have shown two input images below.

[image] [image]

This two images have some black region surrounded by white. It these black can be converted to white, the perimeter of the whole object can be calculated. For example: I got one image (below) from where I could calculate perimeter.

[image]

Are there any function or method in `OpenCV` and `python` for this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `convexHull()` there how to use it (the code is in C++, but you can consider the steps and implement it in Python)

```
cv::namedWindow("origin", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::namedWindow("result", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(R"(ObumF.png)");

cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(gray, gray, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(gray, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > convexHulls(contours.size());

for (unsigned int i(0); i<contours.size(); i++) {
    cv::convexHull(contours[i], convexHulls[i]);
}
cv::imshow("origin", img);

cv::drawContours(img, convexHulls, -1, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
cv::imshow("result", img);

cv::waitKey();
```

**And this is the output:**

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I have converted this `C++` code to `Python` and it works fine exactly like how I need. Thanks again